# Error in magento 2.2 admin panel login

Tags: magento, magento2.2

> {"0":"Source class
>   \"\Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Checkout\AddressInterface\"
>   for
>   \"Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Checkout\AddressRepository\"
>   generation does not exist.","1":"#0
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(112):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass('Temando\\Shippin...',
>   Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Repository))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#2
>   [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#3
>   [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#4
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Relations/Runtime.php(38):
>   class_exists('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#5
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(166):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#6
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(189):
>   Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#7
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/ObjectManager/Config/Developer.php(61):
>   Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->hasPlugins('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#8
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(47):
>   Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer->getInstanceType('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#9
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#10
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#11
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   'Temando\\Shippin...', NULL, 'checkoutAddress...',
>   'Temando\\Shippin...')\n#12
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Temando\\Shippin...',
>   Array, Array)\n#13
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Temando\\Shippin...',
>   Array, Array)\n#14
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#15
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#16
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   'Temando\\Shippin...', NULL, 'ratesRequestDat...',
>   'Temando\\Shippin...')\n#17
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Temando\\Shippin...',
>   Array, Array)\n#18
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Temando\\Shippin...',
>   Array, Array)\n#19
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#20
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#21
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   'Temando\\Shippin...', NULL, 'carrier',
>   'Temando\\Shippin...')\n#22
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Temando\\Shippin...',
>   Array, Array)\n#23
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Temando\\Shippin...',
>   Array, Array)\n#24
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#25
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Event/ObserverFactory.php(33):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#26
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverFactory->get('Temando\\Shippin...')\n#27
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array,
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))\n#28
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('backend_auth_us...',
>   Array)\n#29
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(163):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('backend_auth_us...',
>   Array)\n#30
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('admin', 'admin123')\n#31
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent('login',
>   Array)\n#32
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('admin',
>   'admin123')\n#33
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(78):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login',
>   Array, Array)\n#34
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('admin',
>   'admin123')\n#35
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157):
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#36
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125):
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#37
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#38
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#39
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)\n#40
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#41
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#42
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#43
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#44
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#45
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#46
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#47
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#48
>   /var/www/html/projects/magento22pruthvi/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#49
>   {main}","url":"/projects/magento22pruthvi/admin_nuq1ru/admin/index/index/key/f55f8ffac5f263995a4d5cf199f8941d4582364dba280fb2fddb83f12e7f6fdb/","script_name":"/projects/magento22pruthvi/index.php"}

Answer (score 0):

Check permission of generation folder.

Or try with command:

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

Check permission of var and pub folder.

Run the following command from terminal:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

Thanks